# React Router Pass Param to Component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
const rootEl = document.getElementById('root');

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/">
                <MasterPage />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/details/:id" >
                <DetailsPage />
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>,
    rootEl
);
```

I am trying access the **id** in the DetailsPage component but it is not being accessible. I tried

```
<DetailsPage foo={this.props}/>
```

to pass parameters to the DetailsPage, but in vain.

```
export default class DetailsPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="page">
            <Header />
            <div id="mainContentContainer" >

            </div>
            </div>
    );
    }
}
```

So any idea how to pass the ID on to the DetailsPage ?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

If you want to pass props to a component inside a route, the simplest way is by utilizing the `render`, like this:

```
<Route exact path="/details/:id" render={(props) => <DetailsPage globalStore={globalStore} {...props} /> } />
```

You can access the props inside the `DetailPage` using:

```
this.props.match
this.props.globalStore
```

The `{...props}` is needed to pass the original Route's props, otherwise you will only get `this.props.globalStore` inside the `DetailPage`.

Comment: But why would it not work the way I specified in the ask ?

Comment: First, your code was wrong. Placing a component inside a Route like `<Route exact path="/details/:id" ><DetailsPage /></Route>` was not the same as `<Route exact path="/details/:id" component={DetailsPage} />`. Your code rendered `DetailsPage` even if you visited '/'. Second, when you wrote `<DetailsPage foo={this.props}/>`, `this` referred to `null`. That's why it didn't work.

Comment: This gives an error `Warning: [react-router] You cannot change <Router routes>; it will be ignored`

Comment: Please open a new question and share your code there.

Comment: Please refer to @Alexander Luna 's answer below for a simpler solution.

Comment: from the react-router-dom documentation updating from 5v: If you were using <Route render> to get a hold of the params, you can just useParams inside your route component instead.
https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5

Answer (score 149):

I used this to access the ID in my component:

```
<Route path="/details/:id" component={DetailsPage}/>
```

And in the detail component:

```
export default class DetailsPage extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <h2>{this.props.match.params.id}</h2>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

This will render any ID inside an h2, hope that helps someone.

Comment: It's a simpler and cleaner answer. However, there is a limitation. It doesn't let you pass any additional properties besides what is already there in the route properties object. The accepted answer does.

Answer (score 98):

Since react-router v5.1 with hooks:

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router';

export default function DetailsPage() {
  const { id } = useParams();
}
```

See https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v5-1/

Comment: While more up to date, this only works with functional components.

Comment: in general, you can only use Hooks inside a functional component.

Comment: How do you do for class components?

Comment: That's what they said - this is for functional components.

Answer (score 41):

Use render method:

```
<Route exact path="/details/:id" render={(props) => (
    <DetailsPage id={props.match.params.id}/>
)} />
```

And you should be able to access the id using:

```
this.props.id
```

Inside the DetailsPage component

Comment: this btw also works with the component method: ```<Route path="/..." component={props => <DetailsPage id={props.match.params.id}/>}/>```

Answer (score 14):

Use the component:

```
<Route exact path="/details/:id" component={DetailsPage} />
```

And you should be able to access the `id` using:

```
this.props.match.params.id
```

Inside the `DetailsPage` component

Comment: Interesting this works.
However, why this was out separate because I wanted to pass a variable down to the component.

    `<Route exact path="/details/:id" >
                   <DetailsPage globalStore={globalStore}  />
                </Route>`


Now passing the globalStore doesn't works.

Comment: @Dekel I am trying to do the exact same thing, but I am getting an error. So, I have created a new question. link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52652521/react-router-passing-props-to-component

I am trying to access the id in console as simple as that.

Comment: Instead of 'component' on 'Route' if you use 'render'  it will give good performance

Answer (score 14):

In addition to Alexander Lunas answer ...
If you want to add more than one argument just use:

```
<Route path="/details/:id/:title" component={DetailsPage}/>

export default class DetailsPage extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <h2>{this.props.match.params.id}</h2>
        <h3>{this.props.match.params.title}</h3>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

**FOR version 6 ( 2022 )**

**Note:** using useParams you can easily get your params in your component.

look at the example below

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./compo/home";
import About from "./compo/about";
import Login from "./compo/login";
import "./styles.css";
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="container">
        <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
        <Link to="/about">About</Link>
        <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
      </div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/login/:name" element={<Login />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};
export default App;
```

**Login Component**

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const Login = () => {
  let { name } = useParams();

  return <h1>i am {name ? <b>{name}</b> : "login"}</h1>;
};
export default Login;
```

Answer (score 6):

This is for react-router-dom v6 (I highly suggest using functional components for this)

It's somewhat painful for react-router-dom to keep changing syntax and rules. But here goes nothing.

You can use both `useParams` and `useSelector` to solve this

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const Component = () => {
const { id } = useParams();                              //returns the :id
const page = useSelector((state) => state.something[id]); //returns state of the page

return <div>Page Detail</div>;
}

export default Component;
```

BUT, the problem persist when you also have an action creator and you want to pass it as a props in `connect` function

```
export const connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Component)
```

since we are using `useParams`, it won't be passed to `mapStateToProps` that we created

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
console.log(ownProps)   //wont recognize :id
//hence
return {
  someReducers: state.someReducers[id] //would return an error: 'id' is not defined
 };
};
```

on the other hand, you can't entirely ignore the `connect` function since you need `mapDispatchToProps` to work with your component.

The workaround to this is to create a Higher Order Component `withRouter` function yourself. This was a deprecated react-router-dom helper.

```
//make this
import { useParams, useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { yourActionCreator } from '../actionCreator';

const withRouter = (Child) => {
return (props) => {
 const location = useLocation();
 const navigation = useNavigate();
 const params = useParams();
 return (
   <Child
   {...props}
   params={params}
   navigate={navigate}
   location={location}
   />
  );
 };
};

const Component = () => {
// your component...
return <div> Page Detail </div>
};

export mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
console.log(ownProps)     // would contain the :id params
return {
//something
 }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
yourActionCreator
}

export withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Component));
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's typescript version. works on `"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1"`

```
export const AppRouter: React.StatelessComponent = () => {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/problem/:problemId" render={props => <ProblemPage {...props.match.params} />} />
                <Route path="/" exact component={App} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
};
```

and component

```
export class ProblemPage extends React.Component<ProblemRouteTokens> {

    public render(): JSX.Element {
        return <div>{this.props.problemId}</div>;
    }
}
```

where `ProblemRouteTokens`

> export interface ProblemRouteTokens {
> problemId: string; }

Comment: thank you thats a lot better and simpler works great

Comment: I can confirm it also works in v5.1.2 for class component

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is to use a state and lifecycle hooks in the routed component and a search statement in the `to` property of the `<Link />` component. The search parameters can later be accessed via `new URLSearchParams()`;

```
<Link 
  key={id} 
  to={{
    pathname: this.props.match.url + '/' + foo,
    search: '?foo=' + foo
  }} />

<Route path="/details/:foo" component={DetailsPage}/>

export default class DetailsPage extends Component {

    state = {
        foo: ''
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        this.parseQueryParams();
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        this.parseQueryParams();
    }

    parseQueryParams () {
        const query = new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search);
        for (let param of query.entries()) {
            if (this.state.foo!== param[1]) {
                this.setState({foo: param[1]});
            }
        }
    }

      render() {
        return(
          <div>
            <h2>{this.state.foo}</h2>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are using class component, you are most likely to use GSerjo suggestion. Pass in the params via `<Route>` props to your target component:

```
exact path="/problem/:problemId" render={props => <ProblemPage {...props.match.params} />}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the latest version of (react-router-dom@6.3.0), you can do it like this:

```
 <Route path="path" element={<YourComponent type="simple" />} />
```

Here, **type** is the input passed to **YourComponent**

Comment: so this wouldn't work to retrieve a query param, correct? Like `path="/path/:id"`

Answer (score 2):

I was working on react-router-dom version 6.3.0 and above solution didn't resolve my problem. Then I use something like this and it worked:

```
<Route exact path='/payment-status/:userId/:orderId' element={<PaymentStatus/>}/>
```

And on PaymentStatus.js page I did like this:

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

export const PaymentStatus = () => {

let {userId, orderId}=useParams()

return (
    <div>
    <h2>order ID : {orderId}</h2>
    <h2>user ID : {userId}</h2>
    </div>
  )
}
```

It worked for me. I hope it may help someone. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Simple example with Class, HoC and Router v5

**package.json**

```
"react-router-dom": "5.3.1",
"react-router": "5.3.1",
"@types/react-router-dom": "5.3.3",
```

```
// YourComponent.tsx

import React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps, withRouter } from 'react-router';

export interface PathParams {
    id: string;
}

export interface Props extends RouteComponentProps<PathParams> {}
export interface State {}

class YourComponent extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};

        console.log(props.match.params) // { id: 1 }
        // TypeScript completions
        console.log(props.match.params.id) // 1
    }

    render() {
        return <></>;
    }
}

export default withRouter(YourComponent);
```

```
// App.tsx

import './App.css';

import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch, Router } from 'react-router-dom';

import YourComponent from './YourComponent';

function App(): JSX.Element {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route
                    path="/details/:id"
                    component={() => <YourComponent />}
                />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
<Route exact path="/details/:id" render={(props)=>{return(
    <DetailsPage id={props.match.params.id}/>)
}} />
```

In details page try this...

```
this.props.id
```