# React - how to create a dynamic (using router) details pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

This is my data (in a seperate JS file):

```
const someData= [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "Article 1",
        desc: "Some description lorem ipsum",
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "Article 2",
        desc: "Some description lorem ipsum",
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: "Article 3",
        desc: "Some description lorem ipsum",
    }
]

export default someData;
```

Now I'm mapping the data like this:

```
- Articles.js file

const articleItems = this.state.someData.map(item => 
         <ArticleItem key={item.id} item={item} 
      />)

return(
   <div>{articleItems}</div>
)
```

And listing all articles with only the article title displayed in ArticleItem  component.

```
- articleItem.js file

return(
   <h1>{props.item.title}</h1>
)
```

How can I create so you can click on an article title in the list, which would then go to that specific article (url should be /article/id) and display all data for that specific article?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Router Pass Param to Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45898789/react-router-pass-param-to-component)

Comment: I've checked before but unfortunately it didn't help me. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use React Routers Version 4 to achiever this.

Article.js file-

```
const articleItems = this.state.someData.map(item => 
        <Route key={item.id} path=`/${item.title}/${item.id}` render={
            <ArticleItem 
                {...props}
                item={item}
            />

        } /> 
      />)

return(
   <div>{articleItems}</div>
)
```

In the file where you are rendering the Links render like this.

```
render() {
    return(
        <Link to=`/${item.title}/${item.id}`>{item.title}</Link>
    );
}
```

Don't forget to import Route and Link.
Hope this helps.