# Can't pass parameter data through url in React Router

Tags: reactjs

I want to insert via URL some data like an ID.

Example: somewebsite.com/movie/(ID_GOES_HERE)

But i can't understand how to make it happen. I want the data to go in the url and i want to retrieve it in movie.js, how do i do that?

I installed router dom in the app.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import App from './App';
import MovieDetail from './Movie';

const history = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={history}>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={App}/>
      <Route path='/movie' component={Movie}/>
    </Switch>
  </Router>,
       document.getElementById('root')
);
```

It is expected to show the ID in Movie.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Router Pass Param to Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45898789/react-router-pass-param-to-component)

Comment: There's a great video explaining this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z-CjMnOjg0I

Answer (score 1):

[From react-router documentation:](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/component)

**./App**

```javascript
<Route path="/movie/:movie_id" component={Movie} />;
```

**./Movie**

```javascript
// All route props (match, location and history) are available to Movie
export function Movie(props) {
  return <h1>Show movie {props.match.params.movie_id}!</h1>;
}
```

Comment: The function should be in the same index.js (routes) file? How will Movie.js receive the parameter data?

Comment: No, as you have it will work. When you pass a component to a `Route` with `react-router-dom`, that component will automatically receive props (match, location, and history) from the router context.

Comment: I did it and it throws " Line 5:  Parsing error: Unexpected token"  which corresponds to: "export function Movie(props) {"

Comment: The snippet for `Movie` is just a generic representation of a React component. In this case, a functional component. Yours may very well be a class component. The only part that would be relevant to your case would be `props.match.params.movie_id`. If it's a class component, it would likely be `this.props.match.params.movie_id`.