# how to store a variable within React app URL that can be accessed from the app

Tags: reactjs, parameters, react-router, parameter-passing, url-routing

I got a global variable XX stored in a config.js file and used throught my application as part of APIs end points. this variable frequently change because of backend create every time a new space with data and provide that variable XX.

Because is difficlut for no-dev to change it every time they want to check new data. i need to store that variable value in the url as http:///XX/....

I have no clue on how to start it and was looking for any ideas or inputs

when i have the variable value changed within my url, my application should render and call apis using the new XX value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Router Pass Param to Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45898789/react-router-pass-param-to-component)

Comment: Do you happen to have an example how URL may look like?

Comment: http://<somedomainedeployment>/XX/<routerName>

Answer (score 0):

try parsing DOM's location.pathname or location.href

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting such value in URLs why not putting them anywhere in DOM as a data-attribute of an element, or even as meta property and then read it's value in JS?

Comment: the variable need to be stored there, so any one even not a dev, can change that value within the url and get new data from backend