# I am passing the props to a functional component via Link (react-router-dom) but it says the state is 'undefined'

Tags: reactjs

I need to pass the **id** to a different component.

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Option = () => {
  return (
    <section className="section">
      <Link
        to={{
          pathname: "/person",
          state: { id: "12345" },
        }}
      >
        <button class="button is-primary">Click Me</button>
      </Link>
    </section>
  );
};
export default Option;
```

The component where I am accessing the **id**

```
const Person = (props) => {
  let data = useLocation();
  console.log(data);
  return (
    <section className="section has-text-centered mt-4">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Person;
```

But I am getting state as **undefined**. How do I access the **id** that I have passed in ?

[State is undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9Au3.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the passing props on route component assigned place not ah route navigation

**[Reference Example for passing props to router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45898789/react-router-pass-param-to-component)**

Or else if you really do like passing props on onclick. use `useHistory` hook then pass the state param

> you could receive the state value via `props` in child component

**Updated**

you should pass the render params to the component like

```
<Route path="/person" render={Person} />
```

Is equal to

```
<Route path="/person" render={(params)=><Person {...params}/>} />
```

Then only you can receive the props value on child param

**[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-wildflower-evs1d)**

```
import { Link,useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
    
    const Option = () => {
      const history = useHistory();
      function nav(){
         history.push({
          pathname: '/path',
          state: {  // location state
            update: true, 
          },
        });
      } 
      return (
        <section className="section">
            <button class="button is-primary" onClick={nav}>Click Me</button>
        </section>
      );
    };
    export default Option;
```

Comment: see this example https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-wildflower-evs1d