# this.props.history showing undefine in console in React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In my react app I want to send state to the next path through the history.location.state and history.location.pathname

In my case, it has to push successfully and also showing in history but when I console.log(this.props.history) in the child page showing undefined.

**MyComponent Code**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class MyComponent extends Component {
state = {
          cart: {
                    1:{
                       icon: "URL"
                       id: 1
                       quantity: 1
                       title: "item1"
                      }
                    2:{
                       icon: "URL"
                       id: 2
                       quantity: 1
                       title: "item2"
                      }
             }
        }

submitHandler = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let data = {};
        for (let key in this.state.cart) {
            data[key] = this.state.cart[key]
        }
        console.log("data=",data);
        this.props.history.push({
            pathname: "/result",
            state: { data: data }
        });

    }

render(){
return(
             <div >
               <button  onClick={this.submitHandler}>CONTINUE</button>
             </div>
         )
     }
}
export default withRouter(MyComponent);
```

**Result Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Result extends Component {
render() {

        console.log("ss=",this.props.history);

        return(<div>Result</div>)
}

export default Result;
```

**In Console**

[image]

**Route**

```
<Route path="/result" component={Result} />
```

As shown in the above img in history->location->state is push fine.
But when I console log to this.props showing undefined.

**Also I already use *withRouter* hoc of react-router-dom in export**

Suggest me a solution to this?

Answer (score -1):

May be you are called wrong path. its working and the state variable available on `this.props.location` not a `this.props.history`;

**[Codesanbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-cherry-mtlwp)**

Comment: please post you route initiated component. May be you [have this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65810103/i-am-passing-the-props-to-a-functional-component-via-link-react-router-dom-but/65810234?noredirect=1#comment116359325_65810234)

Comment: @yuvraj https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-cherry-mtlwp check this