# Pass data from one page to another in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have a form on one page that has an image, name and description and a 'book' button. I'd like to pass all of those values to another page.

Here is the page where data is displayed. I have many forms with different data.

```
function TherapistEntry(props) {

    const [therapistDetails, setTherapistDetails] = useState({
        name: ""
    })
    
    function storeName(event) {
        setTherapistDetails({
            name: event.target.value
        })

        
    }
    function redirectPage() {
        // PassName(therapistDetails.name)
        props.history.push('/publicTherapistProfile')
    }

    return (
        <div className="album py-5 bg-light">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    {therapists.map(properties => {
                        return (
                            <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                                <div className="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
                                    <ProfileImage image={properties.image} name="image" />

                                    <div className="card-body">
                                        <p className="card-text" onChange={storeName} name="name">Name: {properties.name}</p>
                                        <p className="card-text" description="description">Description: {properties.description.substring(1, 100)}
                                        </p>
                                        <div className="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                            <div className=" btn-group">
                                                <button onClick={redirectPage} type="button" className="viewButtonHover btn btn-md btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                                            </div>
                                            <small className="text-muted">5 Stars</small>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    )

}

export default withRouter(TherapistEntry)
```

I am trying to test this with the name value first by storing into state. onChange seems like the only way to store it.

i want to then pass these stored values to this page.

```
function IndividualTherapistPage(props) {

    const [passedTherapist, setPassedTherapist] = useState({
        name: ""
    })

    return (
        <div>
            <Header />
            <div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="alignTherapist col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
                        <div className="container">
                            <h2>Individual Therapist Section</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="team-boxed col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
                        <div className="container">
                            <div class="intro">
                                <h2 class="text-center">Therapist </h2>
                                <p class="text-center">Nunc luctus in metus eget fringilla. Aliquam sed justo ligula. Vestibulum nibh erat, pellentesque ut laoreet vitae.</p>
                            </div>
                            <TherapistOfInterestToPurchase name={passedTherapist.name}/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        <h2 style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>Book</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {/* <Footer /> */}
        </div>
    )

}
export default IndividualTherapistPage;
```

Does anyone know how i can do this ?

Comment: Is there a real page-reload between those two or do you just switch two views in your react app?

Comment: Hey @Martin So there is a page under a route lets call it /people and once you click on the view button in the /people route it takes you to another route /peopleInfo lets call it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to use `localStorage` or HTTP GET parameters.

An alternative (more advanced) way is to use a react-router and some kind of global state menagment.

Answer (score 0):

In react you transfer state from parent to child through props. In your scenario you can do by **Redux**. This is use for global state management.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass these values in params to another page and then get it following the example this topic below.

[react-router-pass-param-to-component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45898789/react-router-pass-param-to-component)

It's not necessary to use localstorage or redux for something like that.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this.

1. This is the easiest approach, you can just use the `localStorage` browser API if you don't have too many things to send between pages. You can also do it with the help of [reactjs-localstorage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reactjs-localstorage).
2. This is a little more complicated but also might be better in the long run as you scale, use `Redux` global state management to achieve this.