# React-Router Switch with <Router>..</Router> block (component with props) cannot read URL param with "props.match.params"

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

When I use React-Router the old-fashioned way, with a simple `component={MyComponent}` in my Switch Route, I can get its URL param with `props.match.params`. This works fine:

Container:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/newAgreement/:type" component={NewAgreement} /> 
</Switch>
```

NewAgreement:

```
export default function NewAgreement(props) {
    return (
        <div>
           TYPE: {props.match.params.type} <-- THIS WORKS
        </div>
    );
}
```

The modern React-Router allows you to pass **custom properties** in a Route block, `<Route>..</Route>`, which wasn't possible with the old method. I have custom properties I need to pass, so my Switch Route looks like

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/newAgreement/:type">
       <NewAgreement userInfo="someCustomProperty" />    
    </Route>
</Switch>
```

The new method works when I don't specify any `:` URL params, it passes my properties as it should. But now, with the new block method **and** an `:` URL param, it started breaking with the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined
```

So how can I both pass custom properties within a `<Route>..</Route>` block to my component, and obtain `:...` URL params?

Comment: Does this answerr your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45898789/react-router-pass-param-to-component/51791300?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the module where you declared the `NewAgreement` component do this;

```
import React from "react"
import {useParams} from "react-router"


const NewAgreement = () => {
   const params = useParams();
   console.log(params.id)

   return (
    <>
    ...
    </>
   )
}
```

You can find more information about it on the [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams)